# Firebase - using credentials to authenticate a server with the DB

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jwt, firebase-authentication

I am struggling to find out what is the best way is to authenticate a server with the Firebase DB, as opposed to a user. Do we treat the server the same way we would a regular user, just perhaps with more privileges? What is the canonical way to auth a server or backend process with the DB?

I am guessing that we can generate a custom token (JWT) and use that, but is that JWT valid indefinitely, or do we have to keep generating new tokens?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/

Some code samples would be nice, but I don't really see any.

Comment: Do you just want to authenticate server to read/write in your firebase db ?

Comment: yes pretty much, read-write access to everything if possible

Comment: By any-chance are you using node.js or java server ?

Comment: node.js is our server platform

Answer (score 2):

*Going by your comments:*

Please have a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) . **I think you were looking at wrong docs.** *If you use node.js then you can read/write from server even without authentication.*

And for authentication you can easily setup a service account and then in your firebase security rules handle the server read/write authority as per your needs.

Hope this info helps you.